# Unable to cast object of type List[Microsoft.Graph.ChatMessageHostedContent] to type 'Microsoft.Graph.IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been facing the below issue:

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Graph.ChatMessageHostedContent]'
> to type 'Microsoft.Graph.IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage'

when I am trying to post the images along with the chat message in Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph SDK. I have used the latest Microsoft.Graph.Beta(0.25.0-preview) & Microsoft.Graph.Core(1.21.0) Nuget Packages and used the entire code from the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request

Code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Subject = null,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"
    },  
    HostedContents = (IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage)new List<ChatMessageHostedContent>()
    {
        new ChatMessageHostedContent
        {
            ContentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..."),
            ContentType = "image/png",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@microsoft.graph.temporaryId", "1"}
            }
        },
        new ChatMessageHostedContent
        {
            ContentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..."),
            ContentType = "image/png",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@microsoft.graph.temporaryId", "2"}
            }
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["{id}"].Channels["{id}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You are trying to cast a list of objects to a single object.  You'll need to get the class that implements that interface (`IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage`), create a new instance of it, and add your list to whatever property on the page contains the items (usually called `CurrentPage` on the graph SDK)

Comment: @GuruStron, I have updated the code above, Please help.

Comment: @Pravin , we are not able to reproduce the issue, the code is working fine. Could you please brief about the problem.

Comment: VaraPrasad-MSFT, Thanks for the reply.  Actually, this issue has been resolved.  But the actual problem is posted below. Please help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028614/unable-to-post-inline-images-along-with-the-message-in-microsoft-teams-via-micro

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The issue has been resolved now.

**Working Code**:

```
IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage = new ChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage();

string imageBase64Text = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(currentImageFullPath));

ChatMessageHostedContent chatMessageHostedContent = new ChatMessageHostedContent
{
    ContentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imageBase64Text),
    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"@microsoft.graph.temporaryId", "1"}
    },
};

chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage.Add(chatMessageHostedContent);

//Its working fine with the below code.
chatMessage.HostedContents = chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage;

 ChatMessage sentMessage = await graphClient.Teams["{id}"].Channels["{id}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Please note that the same issue is still coming for the below set of code:

```
List<ChatMessageHostedContent> chatMessageHostedContents = new List<ChatMessageHostedContent>();

chatMessageHostedContents.Add(chatMessageHostedContent);//chatMessageHostedContent is used from above **working code**.

//Below statement actually gives the exception.
chatMessage.HostedContents = (IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage) chatMessageHostedContents;
```

Though the **working code** has resolved this exception, there are still some issues with the HostedContents property of ChatMessage under Microsoft Graph Beta API while posting the image along with text in Microsoft Teams. It gives us the below exception with the above **working code**.

> Code: BadRequest Message: Invalid request body was sent. Inner error:
> AdditionalData:     date: 2020-09-24T19:18:55   request-id:
> 298a3ea5-827f-4375-a0d5-ee619dd834a6  client-request-id:
> 298a3ea5-827f-4375-a0d5-ee619dd834a6 ClientRequestId:
> 298a3ea5-827f-4375-a0d5-ee619dd834a6

I have even tried with the below snippet but it is giving the "UnKnown Error" exception which generally occurs when the Microsoft Graph API is not available.

```
await graphClient.Teams["{id}"].Channels["{id}"].Messages[sentMessage.Id].HostedContents
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(chatMessageHostedContent);
```

The below question refers to the same issue.

[Unable to post inline images along with the message in Microsoft Teams via Microsoft Graph API using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028614/unable-to-post-inline-images-along-with-the-message-in-microsoft-teams-via-micro)