# Unable to post inline images along with the message in Microsoft Teams via Microsoft Graph API using C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been trying to post the images along with the message in Microsoft Teams via MS Graph API using C# but unable to do so.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

System.Security.SecureString passWordSecureString = new System.Security.SecureString();

foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWordSecureString.AppendChar(c);

var clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

string[] scopes = { "ChannelMessage.Send", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "User.Read" };

IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
  .Create(clientId)
  .WithTenantId(tenantId)
  .Build();

//creating the graph user context.
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);            

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Subject = null,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "Hello world </br><div><div>\n<div><span><img height=\"297\" src=\"../hostedContents/1/$value\" width=\"297\" style=\"vertical-align:bottom; width:297px; height:297px\"></span>\n\n</div>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>"
    },  
};

 ChatMessageHostedContent chatMessageHostedContent = new ChatMessageHostedContent
 {
        ContentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASkA..."),
        ContentType = "image/png",
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
             {"@microsoft.graph.temporaryId", "1"}
        }
 };

 IChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage = new ChatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage();

 chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage.Add(chatMessageHostedContent);

 if (chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage.Count > 0)
   chatMessage.HostedContents = chatMessageHostedContentsCollectionPage;

 ChatMessage sentMessage = await graphClient.Teams["{id}"].Channels["{id}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

The image is getting uploaded but it's not showing anything i.e. it's broken/corrupted as shown below:

[image]

I have even tried the below code to add an image to the sent message but its throwing an "unknown error" exception.

```
await graphClient.Teams["{id}"].Channels["{id}"].Messages[sentMessage.Id].HostedContents
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(chatMessageHostedContent);
```

I am able to post the same image along with text successfully using the Post HTTP method in MS Graph Explorer with below URL & payload.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages`

```
{"body":{"contentType":"html","content":"Hello world </br><div><div>\n<div><span><img height=\"297\" src=\"../hostedContents/1/$value\" width=\"297\" style=\"vertical-align:bottom;  max-width: 100%; height:auto\"></span>\n\n</div>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>"},"hostedContents":[{"@microsoft.graph.temporaryId":"1","contentBytes":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASkAAAEpCA...","contentType":"image/png"}]}
```

Can anybody suggest what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Images are sent using "ChatMessageHostedContent" type. Please try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request)

Comment: @Manish-MSFT, Thank you. I have actually referred the same code to post the image in MS Teams but it's throwing the exception as "Invalid request body sent". Please help.

Comment: Did you try using Postman?

Comment: No. I have tested it using Microsoft Graph Explorer and its working fine.

Comment: Use postman and see if it works, and please let us know here.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT, Yes. I've tested it with the Postman & It is working absolutely fine. I can see images appearing in Microsoft Teams using Postman as well. It seems there is an issue in the latest version(prerelease 2.0.0-preview.3) of Microsoft.Graph.Core. I am getting the same "Invalid request body sent" exception for even at the time of posting reactions along with chat messages. The HResult is -2146233088. I've created the below question for a similar issue. Please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199069/getting-invalid-request-body-was-sent-exception-while-posting-the-chatmessager

Comment: @PravinDurgam Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, The issue has been resolved already by updating the Microsoft Graph Beta Assembly.